# SQL Conntection Problem From Web Application

Tags: sql-server-2005, windows-firewall

I have an issue whereby I have a web application installed on one of my Windows Server 2003 virtual machines that  has a database held on a local copy of SQL Express 2005.

This has been working fine - I installed the application find and it created the database in SQL, and the software has been operating fine since.

It has just stopped working as a result of me troubleshooting another part of it, but here's the wierd thing - the thing that has broken it is DISABLING the Windows firewall service on my local machine. It is a Windows 7 machine if that makes a difference.

I had the firewall turned off anyway but I know that it can still sometimes affect traffice. Does anyone know what could have caused this problem? The application communicates with the SQL server on port 1433.

Thanks in advance!

5

Comment: What VM software are you using and what kind of networking is it configured for?

Comment: So you are saying that disabling the firewall on your Windows 7 workstation has broken the asp.net app which runs on a separate Windows 2003 server?  Is the VM running within your Windows 7 workstation?

Comment: Thanks for your replies. I have taken that VM back to a different snapshot and it is now working. Wierd problem though, the VM was running locally.